# Why my AsyncTask doInBackground() is not passing a value to onPostExecute()?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

when i run my code, it returns a value as "null"`

```
private class   MessageActivityLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Contentlist> {
    private LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String> formData;
    Activity activity;

    public MessageActivityLoaderTask(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        formData = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String, String>();
        mProgress.setMessage("Please wait..");
        mProgress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Contentlist doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = getString(R.string.base_url) + "/example/example1/1";
        Contentlist mess = null;
        try {
            mess = RestUtils.exchangeFormData(url, HttpMethod.GET, formData, Contentlist.class);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }
        return mess;

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Contentlist result) {

        if (result== null) {
            Toast message = Toast.makeText(ListobjectsActivity.this, "result is empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            message.show();
        } else {
            ListactivityAdapter adapter = new ListactivityAdapter(this.activity, result.getContents());

            ListView list = (ListView) activity.findViewById(R.id.account);
            list.setAdapter(adapter);
            mProgress.dismiss();
        }

    }`
```

Comment: you need to check if you are getting any exception when you are calling method exchangeFromData

Comment: will it be possible for you to post the code of exchangeFromData (0

Comment: you must add the missing template parameters `... extends AsyncTask<void,void,Contentlist > {...` to make it work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `AsyncTask` looks like it is set up correctly, so `onPostExecute()` will receive the `ContentList` returned by `doInBackgroun()`. Since `onPostExecute()` is seeing a `null`, then `doInBackground()` is returning a null. That means that either `doInBackground()` is getting an exception and `mess` is never set to a non-null value by falling through the `catch` or `RestUtils.exchangeFormData()` is returning a null.

I suggest that you debug the code in this area to see what is really going on. It is not likely to be an `AsyncTask` problem.